How do I fix the "Path_Provider_Foundation" module not found error when using flutter build ios command
App builds perfectly on Android simulator, but with XCODE it keeps throwing the error "Path_Provider_Foundation" module not found.
I have tried:
Flutter clean, Pub get
Cleaning xcode derived data
adding the dependency of "Path_Provider" to my yaml file
reinstalling and setting up xcode
making a clean project and only using the path_provider dependency
Removing the fonts dependency
fixing the targeted version of ios to match between xcode and vs code
remaking the ios directory
All of them end up giving the same error
